# How do you iterate a List (Maybe a)

Tags: elm

I have the following graphQL result:

> [Just { details = Just "Engine failure at 33 seconds and loss of
>   vehicle", launch_year = Just "2006", links = Just { article_link =
>   Just
>   "https://www.space.com/2196-spacex-inaugural-falcon-1-rocket-lost-launch.html"
>   }, mission_name = Just "FalconSat" }]

Based on the following types:

```
type alias Launch =
    { mission_name : Maybe String
    , details : Maybe String
    , launch_year : Maybe String
    , links : Maybe LaunchLinks
    }


type alias Launches =
    Maybe (List (Maybe Launch))


type alias LaunchLinks =
    { article_link : Maybe String
    }
```

I want to List.map through and display the results in unordered list. I started with this:

```
renderLaunch : Launches -> Html Msg
renderLaunch launches =
    div [] <|
        case launches of
            Nothing ->
                [ text "Nothing here" ]

            Just launch ->
                launch
                    |> List.map (\x -> x)
                    |> ul []
```

But I keep getting this error:

> This function cannot handle the argument sent through the (|>) pipe:
>
> 141|                 launch 142|                     |> List.map (\x
>   -> x) 143|                     |> ul []
>                               ^^^^^ The argument is:
>
> ```
> List (Maybe Launch)
> ```
>
> But (|>) is piping it a function that expects:
>
> ```
> List (Html msg)
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `Just launch` case needs to result in a `List (Html msg)` but the code results in a different type being returned.

When you are using `List.map (\x -> x)`, it is essentially a no-op. You are iterating over a `List (Maybe Launch)` and returning the same thing. I'd recommend creating another function that takes a `Maybe Launch` value and use that as your mapping function. For example:

```elm
displayLaunch : Maybe Launch -> Html Msg
displayLaunch launch =
    case launch of
        Nothing -> text "No launch"
        Just l -> text (Debug.toString l)
```

Now you can plug that into your mapping function:

```elm
Just launch ->
    launch
        |> List.map displayLaunch
        |> ul []
```

But, whoops! Now you get a new error indicating:

```
The 2nd branch is:

    Html Msg

But all the previous branches result in:

    List (Html msg)
```

The problem here is that we are now returning a `ul` from the `Just launch` branch and we need to return a list of html. You can use `List.singleton` to create a list with just one item:

```elm
Just launch ->
    launch
        |> List.map displayLaunch
        |> ul []
        |> List.singleton
```